# Which happens when user send multiple Asynchronous requests from a client to specific web service in c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asynchronous, iis

I have an ASP.Net MVC project in a specific page which has multiple partial pages.

Each partial page sends an Asynchronous request to a specific web service in a server.

Does IIS create a separate instance for each request?(run each web service as parallel or create a sequential queue for all requests).

I have 10 partial pages and each partial page send a request in javascript like below:

`$http({
        method: 'Post',
        url: WebServiceUrl,
        params: params
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        ...
    });`

And on the other side(web service):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string MyWebService(int ApplicationId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (xRDSEntities db = new xRDSEntities())
            {
                ....
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return  "Error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Does IIS create a separate instance" - instance of what? I'd expect each request to be handled in its own thread (or "async context") - but that doesn't mean that this is correct. I'd simply make a little Test-App to try that out.

Comment: if you're using `async` on server side, it will work as you expect. if you're not using, each asynchronous from client (ajax) will be blocked until the previous one is finished. Read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: Users/Clients **always** send multiple requests to a service. How the client does that doesn't matter to the server.

Comment: Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/web/applicationpool-element-web-settings

Comment: You should be asking how the *browser* and *Javascript* handles the requests. The server always processes requests concurrently. If something blocks, it's your browser code

Comment: @ElmerDantas no, not at all. `async` has absolutely nothing to do with request blocking. IIS **always** uses multiple threads to process multiple requests. `async` is used to avoid wasting those threads. You can fire 100 requests in parallel, IIS will use as many threads as required to server all of them. Each request will be processed by a **different** Controller instance anyway.

Comment: @Fildor no need for testing. That's how IIS and ASP.NET work since Day 1. Even if you don't use any asynchronous calls on the server, each request is handled by a different thread. The threads come from a threadpool to avoid wasting time to create new threads all the time. The pool's size changes but there *is* an upper limit that's used to avoid flooding the server with more requests than it can handle.

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour This sounds like a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a performance problem (X) and think it's caused by Y (IIS blocking), so you try to solve Y. When that fails, you ask about Y, not the actual problem X. What is your  *actual* problem?

Comment: @Fildor. an instance of web service. how can you test it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's exactly what I was assuming. I was just not 100% sure because I only worked with Java-based servers like Tomcat so far. But if you backup that claim, it's true: no need for testing.

Comment: @Elmer Dantas. i'm using sync on server side.

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour It's not exactly an instance of the webservice but a "context" that is handled concurrently for the individual requests. Actually you don't need to test this. It's documented behaviour.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, I've probably misinterpreted his question.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I don't have any problem with client side because all requests send Asynchronously at the same time.

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour then what is the point of the question? *Why* are you asking? Different requests get served by different threads. Why do you think the server has anything to do with asychronous processing?

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour wait, what does `Each partial page sends an Asynchronous request to a specific web service` mean? Who is making that request? Javascript? C# code embedded in the view (very bad idea?)? Why doesn't the *controller* make the web service calls? Please post the code that actually makes the requests

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos all requests send from HTTP service in javascript and my question was: Does IIS create a separate instance for each request(from one user on specific web service)? alternate: Does IIS run all requests concurrently?

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour and, as I and others commented before, IIS/ASP.NET  **always** uses a different thread for each request and always did. Otherwise it wouldn't be used in production web sites. This is a fundamental concept explained in ASP.NET tutorials. So, why are you asking at all? Is it just (downvotable) laziness or (more likely) concern caused by something else? Have you encountered blocking? Delays? Low throughput?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos I got my answer: `IIS/ASP.NET always uses a different thread for each request and always did`. Nevertheless, all requests run concurrently even if the requested resource and the user be same and the web service be synchronous. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments the all requests run concurrently even if the requested resource and the user be same and the web service be synchronous